# Project Regex result of column - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection in which I do have list of URL's from different domains (e.g http://xy.com/testlink,http://ab.com/anotherlink, http://ab.com/secondlink). I am trying to build up a query through which I can get the distinct of domain names only not the full path. I came across the group by clause but couldn't find a way to project the regex output from the existing column.

In the above example, the expected out is ['http://xy.com', 'http://ab.com']

Comment: You might try using `$substr` or `$split`

Comment: OH yes... thanks for the link!!!